# DOS command to bring up "Turn off computer" window?

Tags: batch-file, shutdown, logoff

I would like to create a batch file that brings up the Windows "Turn off computer" window, rather than the user doing so through the usual Start / Turn off Computer method.

Here's a picture of the window I would like to bring up using a DOS batch file :-

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5exhq.jpg

Does anyone know of a way to do this using a DOS / Batch file method ?

Many thanks,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Shutdown windows with batch file](http://samanathon.com/windows-tip-shutdown-your-computer-with-a-batch-file/)

Comment: Hi, I cannot shut down windows with a batch file, as permissions will not allow the "shutdown" command to run. That's why I didn't ask how to shut down windows with a batch file, I asked how to bring the window up. Thanks for the help, but can you help with the specific question ? Cheers.

Comment: Sorry, have you tried this? Create a new txt file somewhere on your system, open it and put in this one line:
(new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application")).ShutdownWindows();
Save and Close the file. Change the extension to js

Comment: That's brilliant, and works very well, thanks very much Jason. To give some background as to why I need to do this, I need to log shut-down times in a text-file-log, and I cannot think of any other way to do it (I cannot use group-policy) other than doing something like this, where a script can be double-clicked, the script will write the system time to a log, and then bring this window up, where the user will shut down normally. That being the case then, how would I incorporate this .js script with a .bat script that does the time-logging? Can I call the .jz script from the .bat file ? Cheers

Comment: Your on your own there! haha but maybe this may help with that..http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090717063113AAEzenT

Comment: Yes, thanks Jason, that looks like it will get me away. Thanks very much for your assistance here, you've been extremely helpful.